# How to pass input data dynamically inside Angular Library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to take input from the user and then pass it to API endpoint which is in services section but the services section has to converted into a library. So how can achieve this data transfer without updating the library or putting hardcoded values inside it again and again?

Answer (score 0):

try using type `any` for the input data in the service library. this is how you will be able to pass any data type the api would receive. Even if the api request data type changes, you don't have to change the service input data type.